# Rollback Issue after update in the database

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I have an odd problem that doesn't happen every time. I'm doing an update using hibernate but in some cases the data disappears from the database after 10 seconds more or less.

I've already checked the logs and nothing gets executed after the update, so it must be a rollback but I don't know how

```java
repository.realMerge(constat);
repository.flush();
repository.refresh(constat);
```

Comment: How is the transaction set up?

Comment: I call merge => flush => refresh

Comment: Thats not how a transaction works